# extract lines based on a column

Tags: awk

I have some files containing the following data.

```
 160-68 160 68 B-A OD-CA 3.80247
 160-68 160 68 B-A OG-C 3.73454
 160-69 160 69 B-A OD1-NZ 2.76641
 160-69 160 69 B-A OG-CA 3.54446
 160-69 160 69 B-A OE-NZ2 4.24609
 160-69 160 69 B-A OG-O 3.97644
 160-69 160 69 B-A OG-H 1.82292
```

I need to extract lines having any of the following pairs  OD-NZ, NZ-OD, OE-NZ, NZ-OE, OE-NH, NH-OE in the 5th column. What is the easy way to do this?

Desired Output

```
160-69 160 69 B-A OD1-NZ 2.76641
160-69 160 69 B-A OE-NZ2 4.24609
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please refer to this aid on how to ask a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask   - also bear in mind the following: what have you tried? show us your code and then we'll be in a better position to help you out.

Comment: These pairs have digits after them? How many?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$5 ~ /OD[0-9]*-NZ[0-9]*|NZ[0-9]*-OD[0-9]*|OE[0-9]*-NZ[0-9]*|NZ[0-9]*-OE[0-9]*|OE[0-9]*-NH[0-9]*|NH[0-9]*-OE[0-9]*/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be easiest if you need to add/delete/modify any of the pairs you're interested in in future. With GNU awk for gensub():

```
awk -v pairs="OD-NZ NZ-OD OE-NZ NZ-OE OE-NH NH-OE" '
  BEGIN{ split(pairs, tmp); for (i in tmp) pairsArr[tmp[i]] }
  gensub(/[[:digit:]]/,"","g",$5) in pairsArr
' file
 160-69 160 69 B-A OD1-NZ 2.76641
 160-69 160 69 B-A OE-NZ2 4.24609
```

You can do the same with gsub() and a variable in any awk.

Or if you prefer:

```
awk -v pairs="OD-NZ|NZ-OD|OE-NZ|NZ-OE|OE-NH|NH-OE" '
BEGIN { pairs = "^" gensub(/([-|]|$)/,"[[:digit:]]*\\1","g",pairs) "$" }
$5 ~ pairs
' file
 160-69 160 69 B-A OD1-NZ 2.76641
 160-69 160 69 B-A OE-NZ2 4.24609
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -P 'OD\d?-NZ\d?|NZ\d?-OD\d?|....' file
```

if you love using awk, get `$5` and check with same regex.

Comment: ITYM `\d -> [[:digit:]]` :-). I get where you're coming from, I just don't think `\d` would work with most awks and since you said `same regex`...